# AngularJS Access Global Variable Under Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a global variable like following.

```
var Lightbox = {};
............
 Lightbox.openModal = function (newImages, newIndex, modalParams) {
...............
}
```

I would like to access this variable under directives like the following way.

```
app.directive('productBuyers', ['Product', function(Product) {

    return {

        restrict : 'E',

        scope : {},

        template : '<div>' +
            '<p class="product-buyers-f bold" ng-show="photos.length">Others:</p>' +
            '<
            '<div class="product-buyer square" ng-click="openLightboxModal($index)" ng-repeat="photo in photos | limitTo:3" ng-style="{\'background-image\':\'url(\' + photo.image + \')\'}"></div>' + 
            '<div class="clear"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>',

        link : function($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.photos = [];

            function getImages() {

            }
            $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
                Lightbox.openModal($scope.photos, index);
              };
            getImages();

        }

    }

}]);
```

I have tried by passing "$window" to the directive parameter and also using scope but it's not working. It's showing undefined "Lightbox".

Comment: Why did you write `**Lightbox`? Looks like you have syntax errors in your code. If you have a global it shouldn't throw error. What is the order of execution of these scripts?

Comment: **Lightbox is not a fact. I just clicked "B" from stackoverflow editor. My Lightbox script is running before productBuyers directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.Lightbox` and also `window.Lightbox.openModal = function(...)`